# how to keep ram data when pm2 restart?Nodejs

Tags: node.js, server, pm2

I keep process by pm2,and when I get a bug,pm2 restart the node application,I want to keep the user data in ram,yes,I put some user data in ram,and hope to keep it alive when node process has restarted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use something like redis to persist your data into your memory.

Comment: Any other ways？

Comment: In order to do that you have to persist your data into secondary memory(hdd), or use a memory db. Take a look at [node-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-persist) module for a simple data persist library, if you don't want to use redis